# Will there be consequences or issues if I install XQuartz?

Tags: macos, applications, xquartz

I need to install **XQuartz** to install **Inkscape**, a vector graphics application.

May I know if issues would come when I install XQuartz? I'm new to OS X and I find the need to install an application to install another application unusual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's absolutely fine, it's essentially a standalone application that you can uninstall again anytime. Except when you're running Inkscape, you'll never know it's there.

In fact, XQuartz used to come on the OS X install DVD (though it wasn't installed by default), but like Java and Flash, Apple just prefer not to package and ship those things with the OS any more, and require you to install it separately direct from the developer.

If you're still not sure, there is a [native port of Inkscape in progress](https://inkscape.org/en/~su_v/galleries/osxmenu-r12922/) that doesn't require XQuartz, but it was a little buggy last time I tried.

Comment: Thanks. Can I know what bugs you encountered with the native port of Inkscape?

Comment: Only specific thing I can immediately remember is that it took a very long time to start up. I haven't tried it in 6 months though, so I expect they've fixed up a lot since then. You can see the current official list of known issues on the [download page](https://inkscape.org/en/~su_v/★inkscape-osxmenu-r12922-gtk2).

Comment: Great. I'll probably use the version that needs XQuartz. I frequently use Inkscape. Thanks again.

Comment: On second thought, could these problems happen when I install XQuartz? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260430/xquartz-crashing-in-infinite-loop-el-capitan-edition?rq=1

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238126/terrible-fonts-on-external-display-after-installing-xquartz?rq=1

Comment: All I can say is that I've never seen that error. Judging by the responses and an internet search for similar issues, it seems it's most likely to happen if you've previously installed some other version of XQuartz, or have installed it from a different source such as [Fink](http://finkproject.org), both of which might have made changes to configuration files in your home directory that cause the latest version to fail.